# Team City variables and Webpack

Tags: webpack, teamcity

I'm trying to use Team City to pass environment variables into webpack. im fairly new to both.

The goal is to set some access tokens during the build process since they differ by environment.

Does anyone have any advice on setup or execution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Once you add env.NAME parameter to the TeamCity Build Configuration, NAME environment variable will be present in all the processes launched within the build.

Comment: How would one access that with webpack?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the environment variables in TeamCity:

1. Go to the settings of your build.
2. Choose the Parameters tab.
3. Click on the "Add new parameter" button.
4. Choose the "Environment variable" kind.
5. Edit the value and name of your variable (keep the `env.` prefix).

[image]

Then install the [DotEnv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack) package for Webpack.

Edit your webpack configuration file (`webpack.config.js`) to add the `systemvars` parameter to *true* for this plugin:

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    // ...
    new Dotenv({
      systemvars: true,
    })
  ],
};
```